# How to implement server side pagination with limit enforcement in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I want to allow client to infinite scroll.
The things is that I don't want to allow client define the limit (chunk) per data load, the reason is that it's not secure for me, since the collection contains lot of documents and the client will be allowed to ask for unlimited number of documents with a little js injects.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't present a good use case here. You cite security as a reason for not allowing the client to specify the limit, but that's not a security hole in itself.

Comment: You can always rate-limit the requests. You can take a look at the [DDP Rate Limiter](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ddp-rate-limiter) package and use it directly or as an inspiration.

Comment: @Mikkel if hacker can request enormous data chunks, actually it can shut down your servers if he does it right. so let's keep it as security hole.

Answer (score 1):

You can set manually limit on publication(like 25 documents per load).

```
 Meteor.publish('allDocuments', function(pageNavigator = 0) {
        return CustomCollection.find({},{ skip:pageNavigator, limit:25      
        });      
    });
```

Where pageNavigator is a session value used for paging(e.g. 0, 25, 50 ...).
This way it will always return max 25 documents per load.

Comment: And then, when the user scroll down and data has to be retrieve, there is need to stop subscription and start again?

Comment: Meteor is a smart enough to handle all of that for you. Check this link https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-connection

Comment: skip is searching all of the documents, so if you have 150k records this is not good at all for performance.